# Multiple LIKE statements in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, sql-like

This is what I'm trying to achieve in it's simplest form:

```
SELECT 
    p.ProductId,
    p.ProductName,
    p.SKU
FROM tbl_Product p
WHERE (p.ProductName LIKE '%white%' OR p.SKU LIKE '%white%')
AND (p.ProductName LIKE '%cup%' OR p.SKU LIKE '%cup%')
```

I'm trying to do this in a UDF, which accepts a comma separated parameter of all the search terms.

I tried splitting that parameter into a temporary table and trying a join, like this:

```
DECLARE @SearchText nvarchar(1000) SELECT @SearchText='white,cup'

DECLARE @SearchTerms TABLE (String nvarchar(200))
INSERT INTO @SearchTerms (String)
SELECT '%' + String + '%' FROM dbo.CsvSplitString(@SearchText)

SELECT 
    p.ProductId,
    p.ProductName,
    p.SKU
FROM tbl_Product p
JOIN @SearchTerms s ON (p.ProductName LIKE s.String OR p.SKU LIKE s.String)
```

But that doesn't return what I want - it returns any records where  the Name or SKU matches either of the search terms. I need it to return like the first query, where the Name or SKU matches all of the search terms (I think that makes sense).

Would be massively appreciative of a push in the right direction - let me know if you need me to be more specific.

Note: full text searching is not a viable option at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to "match all of the search terms" doesn't that mean that you can only have two(2) search terms, since you only have two columns to match against?

Comment: the number of search terms can be infinite. for example i could search for "white plastic cup". So for each term, either ProductName or SKU must match. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It does not make sense.  How could only two columns match ***all*** of three distinct search terms?  It's not possible the way that you have described it.

Comment: @seanxe, ignore him it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Really?  Following the description, if the search terms where "white,plastic,cup", then the corresponding WHERE conditions would be: *(ProductName='white' OR SKU='white') AND (ProductName='plastic' OR SKU='plastic') AND (ProductName='cup' OR SKU='cup')*.  There is no combination of values for ProductName and SKU that can satisfy this requirement, because two columns ***cannot*** match *all* of three different values.

Comment: the where conditions would be multiple LIKE statements, so it's perfectly valid to assume that either ProductName or SKU would match. See my first code snippet - this is what i'm effectively trying to achieve.

Comment: @seaxne:  could you please provide the SQL example for three search terms, done like your first example for two search terms?  Because as far as I can tell, my example above should be what you are describing.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, it's not `=`, it's `like '%...%'`, which means "contains". He's basically doing a normal textual search in 2 fields with multiple keywords. Go look at Google if you want an example of searching for multiple words in two fields (page title and page contents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query below should do it but it may not be the fastest!

```
DECLARE @SearchText nvarchar(1000) SELECT @SearchText='white,cup'
DECLARE @keywords TABLE (keyword nvarchar(255))
DECLARE @keywordCount int

INSERT INTO @keywords (keyword) SELECT * FROM dbo.CsvSplitString(@SearchText)
SET @keywordCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @keywords)


SELECT *
FROM tbl_Product p
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM
        (SELECT productId
        FROM tbl_Product, @keywords
        WHERE productname like '%' + keyword + '%' or sku like '%' + keyword + '%' 
        GROUP BY productid
        HAVING COUNT(*) = @keywordCount
        ) matches 
    WHERE p.ProductId=matches.ProductId
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you can run a cursor over `@SearchTerms` and loop over the results, checking for each item if it's present in your results.

You most likely won't have many search items (5-6 would be so rare), so the cursor cost should be negligible compared to running `like` over and over on your text. And that shouldn't be too expensive either.

Edit: What I've done in the past for searches is send the query in plain text to the server instead of relying on stored procedures, so I could piece together my conditions myself. You can do the same with dynamic queries and `exec` on the server if you so wish. This way seems pretty hacky and it's not obvious it's a performance improvement. Food for thought.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i've always tried to steer clear from cursors because i always seem to read bad things about performance, but i can see where you're coming from re: number of search terms. i'll definitely have a look into it now.

Comment: the site was originally in linq to sql, and was just being punished under the load so we decided to move it all in to sql - the peformance gains have been huge. it may be worth pointing out as well that this question is a small part of a much larger query. thanks for your answer though, food for thought with cursors.

Comment: It's at least a quick to implement solution while you look into something else (if you still feel the need for it), should be like 6 lines of code.